# Typescript: how to call a Javascript function with a callback

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I am using Ionic with Typescript. I need to access the [following api](https://github.com/alexdrel/cordova-plugin-icloudkv):

```
load(key, successCallback/*(value)*/, failCallback)
```

In Typescript I do the following:

```
cordova.plugins.icloudkv.load('key').then((data) => {
    console.log(data);
    alert('load key: ' + JSON.stringify(data));
      });
    }
  }).catch((e) => {
    console.error(JSON.stringify(e));
    this.doAlert('iCloud: ' + JSON.stringify(e));
  });
```

However, the `alert` is never getting fired.

**Question**

Please can someone advise what's the best way to invoke the javascript function using typescript?

Thanks

Comment: Well does it return a promise? If not than you probably need to do something like: `cordova.plugins.icloudkv.load('key', () =>{}, () =>{})` ??

Comment: You can't treat it like it's a promise if it's not. Either convert it to a promise (or observable - https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/fromcallback.md), or note that TS is just a subset of JS and call it exactly as you would have before, passing in a callback (arrow) function.

Comment: You can use methods on your class as success/error handlers. `cordova.plugins.icloudkv.load('key', this.someClassMethod, this.someOtherClassMethod);`

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky but note that `this` may behave in unexpected ways if you do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the api you've provided your code should look more like:

```
cordova.plugins.icloudkv.load('key', 
  (data)=>{
    console.log(data);
    alert('load key: ' + JSON.stringify(data));
  }, (e)=>{
    console.error(JSON.stringify(e));
    this.doAlert('iCloud: ' + JSON.stringify(e));
});
```

Comment: Thank you, I am just testing it, and will mark this as the answer if it works

Answer (score 1):

Are you getting any errors in the console?

Your code assumes that `load` returns a Promise. See if this works, since the example explicitly asks for two callbacks in the `load` method:

```
cordova.plugins.icloudkv.load('key', (data) => {
        console.log(data);
        alert('load key: ' + JSON.stringify(data));
     }, (e) => {
         console.error(JSON.stringify(e));
         this.doAlert('iCloud: ' + JSON.stringify(e));
 });
```

Comment: Also, bear in mind that with arrow functions `this` will have a different scope. My example assumes that this is the scope you want.

Comment: Thank you. You have the correct answer. But its the same as the answer fro someone who posted just before you, so I'll mark there's as the correct answer. You get an up vote haha

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer to work with a `Promise` even though the api doesn't use one then construct a `Promise` around the call:

```
new Promise((resolve, reject) => cordova.plugins.icloudkv.load('key', resolve, reject))
.then((data) => {
    console.log(data);
    alert('load key: ' + JSON.stringify(data));
      });
    }
  }).catch((e) => {
    console.error(JSON.stringify(e));
    this.doAlert('iCloud: ' + JSON.stringify(e));
  });
```